# poisson process limit, SLLN

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-limit-theorems, poisson-process

The number of cars that arrive at a parking lot follow a Poisson process with $\lambda > 0$.
Be $T_1,T_2 ...$ The time of arrive between each car, so that $T_1 + T_2 + T_2  ... + T_n$ is the arrival time of the nth car

to which converges in probability

$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}T_{i}^2$ when $n \rightarrow \infty  $

I am not sure what to do with the summation, i think that the solution has something to do with the exponential distribution

the mean squared + variance $\rightarrow  \frac{1}{\lambda^2} + \frac{1}{\lambda^2} = \frac{2}{\lambda^2} $
because n tends to infinity  so the the dispersion measure will tend to an exponenential distribution (SLLN)

i will appreciate if someone can clarify me more on the solution,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(T_i)$ is i.i.d and so is $(T_i^{2})$. Hence, SLLN shows that $\frac  1 n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} T_i^{2} \to ET_1^{2}$. This is just the second moment of the $exp(\lambda)$ distribution.